# ServiceStack IAutoQuery namespace could not be found?

Tags: servicestack

I'm playing around with ServiceStack's AutoQuery, but getting stuck with this. I've put `Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature { MaxLimit = 100});` up, and tried to add all the namespaces, but no luck so far. Thanks.

UPDATE: I'm following the main, ServiceInterface, ServiceModel structure. When I put `public IAutoQuery AutoQuery { get; set; }` into main, it could be recognized. But not working in ServiceInterface. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

All the AutoQuery functionality is contained in the single [AutoQueryFeature.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/AutoQueryFeature.cs) which is in the `ServiceStack` namespace.

This is also where you'll find the [IAutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/773aac107fc2e0fe6a823acef0c3bad20f686da0/src/ServiceStack.Server/AutoQueryFeature.cs#L513) interface (also in the ServiceStack namespace). This means if you can find `AutoQueryFeature` you'll also be able to find `IAutoQuery` by default, if you're having build errors, it's likely there's some other issue, i.e. try a clean build otherwise you maybe you need to restart Visual Studio.

The AutoQuery feature is in the **ServiceStack.Server** NuGet package:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Server
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't notice it wasn't installed.